# Log user in via frontend in Selenium Capybara Rspec Tests

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I want to be logged in as a user during my tests that use javascript, so I figured I should have a helper method which logs a user in via frontend.
However with the helper

```
    def log_user_in_via_frontend(user)
        visit root_path
        fill_in 'user_session_login', :with => user.login
        fill_in 'user_session_password', :with => user.password
        click_on('Login')
    end
```

I am able to be logged in and am redirected to the right page as long as I don't put `:js => true` at the end. I call this helper via

```
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    log_user_in_via_frontend(user)
```

Visiting root_path afterwards yields `No route matches {:controller=>\"users\", :action=>\"show\", :id=>#<User id: nil, login: nil`...

What's the best way to have an logged in user in my selenium tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually by now this works for me. I am not sure what for exactly, but I think the key is deactivate transitional fixture, and to have database cleaner do the cleaning.